# What does Nvidia mean when they say samples per pixel in regards to DLSS?

Tags: deep-learning, nvidia, antialiasing

> "NVIDIA researchers have successfully trained a neural network to find
>   these jagged edges and perform high-quality anti-aliasing by
>   determining the best color for each pixel, and then apply proper
>   colors to create smoother edges and improve image quality. This
>   technique is known as Deep Learning Super Sample (DLSS). DLSS is like
>   an “Ultra AA” mode-- it provides the highest quality anti-aliasing
>   with fewer artifacts than other types of anti-aliasing.
>
> DLSS requires a training set of full resolution frames of the aliased
>   images that use one sample per pixel to act as a baseline for
>   training. Another full resolution set of frames with at least 64
>   samples per pixel acts as the reference that DLSS aims to achieve."

https://developer.nvidia.com/rtx/ngx

At first I thought of sample as it is used in graphics, an intersection of channel and a pixel. But that really doesn't make any sense in this context, going from 1 channel to 64 channels ?

So I am thinking it is sample as in the statistics term but I don't understand how a static image could come up with 64 variations to compare to? Even going from FHD to 4K UHD is only 4 times the amount of pixels. Trying to parse that second paragraph I really can't make any sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

16 bits × RGBA equals 64 samples per pixel maybe? They say at least, so higher accuracy could take as much as 32 bits × RGBA or 128 samples per pixel for doubles.